# Why flutter app doesn't load previously written data when relaunch of the app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have wrote image file to flutter application document directory using image picker but it says path is null when relaunch(Go to home screen and relaunch the app again) the flutter app.I can't find the exact problem causing this.

Path is load when start up of the application.

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((directory) {
        _localPath = directory.path;

    });
}
```

Image selection.

```
_decideImageView() {

        if(FileSystemEntity.typeSync('$_localPath/name.jpg') == FileSystemEntityType.notFound){
        return AssetImage("assets/example.jpeg");
        }else {

        return FileImage(File('$_localPath/name.jpg'));
}
```

Image picking

```
_openGallery(BuildContext context) async{

  var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  this.setState((){
    imageFile = picture;
  });

  Directory pathd = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String path =pathd.path;
  final File newImage = await imageFile.copy('$_localpath/name.jpg');
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((directory) {
       _localPath = directory.path;

   });
```

Does not guarantee that the _localPath will load at the time _decideImageView() is called.
Add print to check this:

```
_decideImageView() {
print(_localPath);
        if(FileSystemEntity.typeSync('$_localPath/name.jpg') == FileSystemEntityType.notFound){
        return AssetImage("assets/example.jpeg");
        }else {

        return FileImage(File('$_localPath/name.jpg'));
}
```

This work for me after reload/restart app:

```
_decideImageView(BuildContext context) async {
  Directory pathd = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  return Navigator.of(context)
      .push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: InkWell(
          child: PhotoView(
            imageProvider: FileImage(File('${pathd.path}/name.jpg')),
            backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
            minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 0.9,
            maxScale: 4.0,
          ),
          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }));
}
```

Comment: I'll try and let you know